# FFmpeg : Check if the aac bitstream is malformed or not

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, html5-audio

I want to upload few sets of videos on my server and later play them in the HTML5 video tag. But some of them are not playing.

I checked the audio stream and video stream of the video, they have **AAC** and **H264** codec respectively.So nothing seems wrong to me.

Then I tried re-encoding it, i got the following message:

```
malformated aac bitstream, use -absf aac_adtstoasc
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Operation not permitted
```

However I don't want to encode the videos before upload and **just need to check** if video has a malformed aac or h264 bitsream.

> PS. Users are limited and will be provided with videos h264 and aac
>   encoded for the upload.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`malformated aac bitstream, use -absf aac_adtstoasc` doesn't mean the input stream is invalid. It's rather the re-encoding that's invalid. The idea is that you're using an MPEG-2 transport stream as input and the AAC stream in it uses the ADTS format.

If you want to re-encode the file and change the container to FLV or MP4 for example you MUST use the bitstream filter [aac_adtstoasc](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#toc-aac_005fadtstoasc) to remove the ADTS header:

```
-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc
```

To view the input streams you can use `ffprobe`. Eg:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams [input]
```

Verifying file integrity is another matter.

If the input is MPEG-TS it will not play in HTML5 natively. Check the uploaded format and re-encode to a HTML5 supported format.